# Replace the video edit with another video keeping the in and out timings

Tags: premiere

I'm editing a pre-rendered photo gallery template in Premiere Pro CC 2014.

The entire photo gallery clip is a single video clip, which I have cut in many places to make some changes. I have made several edits to this include speed changes, perspective correction, etc..

Now I have a second set of photo gallery **exactly same** as the first one with different set of photos and wish to keep the same edits as the first one.

Is there any way to replace the second set with first set edit.
I'm aware of the Replace Clip from Bin feature. But it always sets the In point to the beginning of the clip. Is there any way to replace the clip as well as sync the mark in and out points?

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround:

- Open the new clip in its own project.
- Set the "in" point and the "out" point.
- Export that as a new clip (with lossless video quality, if you can pull that off).
- Open your other project.
- Use Replace Clip from Bin, and replace it with the clip you just exported.  In the new clip, the "in" point *is* the beginning of the clip!